# XBAP application failing on second browing domain

Tags: dns, manifest, xbap

I deployed an XBAP application on two different servers with different domain names. Unfortunately, It loads ok on first browsing domain and throws the exception below when browsing second. If I use mage -cc to clear the cache, again, it loads fine on first browsing domain and throws exception on second.

> ERROR SUMMARY     Below is a summary of the errors, details of these
>   errors are listed later in the log. An exception occurred while
>   downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:
>
> Unable to install this application because an application with the
>   same identity is already installed. To install this application,
>   either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall
>   the preexisting application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Manifest file, change the version of the application identity or republish, check in the project properties ->publish->check automatically increment revision with each publish. Then publish it and then run it.